# Quantum pendulum undergoing small oscillations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

In N. Zettili’s book of quantum mechanics, I came across this problem:

> Consider a pendulum undergoing small oscillations with angular frequency $\omega$ =$\sqrt{g/l}$. Show that quantum energy levels and the corresponding degeneracies of the pendulum are given by E=(n+1)$\hbar$$\omega$ and g=n+1.

Now, I have been trying to figure out a quicker way to solve the problem but I am unable to find that. Is the only way to solve this is to write the quantum analogue to the classical hamiltonian and then solving the whole thing or is there some trick involved to get the final result rather easily?

Comment: Hint: in the small-angle limit, the quantum analogue to the classical Hamiltonian is literally the harmonic-oscillator Hamiltonian.

Comment: @probably_someone yeah I saw that but then answer wasn't the same as the one given. Is it like for 2 dimensions, we can directly write (n+1/2+1/2)$\hbar$$\omega$?

Comment: One notes that the expressions for energy levels and degeneracy are just those for a system of two identical independent harmonic oscillators.